# Laravel route to same depth

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have a site in a subfolder, `example.com/mysite`. I have a route there, `login`, which is accessed via `example.com/mysite/login`. This is the route:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.com'), function()
{

    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    });

    Route::get('/login/', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@login'));

})
```

The problem is, when I have a link in my view like so:

```
<a href='{{{ route('login') }}}'>Login page</a>
```

It displays the path `example.com/login` instead of `example.com/mysite/login`. It think this has something to do with  the domain group, but I don't know how to tell it to keep the current subdirectory. I've tried changing the domain to `example.com/mysite` in the group command, but that just causes an error. The redirection to login works, but how do I get the correct link in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, this is because when it generates the route, it uses the domain provided in the group instead of getting it from the url. It can be overriden though, by specifying an empty domain in the individual route match, like so:

```
Route::get('/login/', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@login', 'domain' => ''));
```

This will allow it to ignore the domain specified in the group function. Unfortunately, from what I can tell, you need to do this for all of them.

Comment: From what I see here, it looks more like you renamed your route name to `'as' => 'login'`. This should result in the link working now. See my answer to get some more insight about how your redirect works and how the views access the routes.

Comment: @MatthiasS Oops, sorry, that was a typo, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

Your routes do not follow a relative path. Even if you are in example.com/mysite, your route is made within the example.com domain.
Your redirect redirects you to example.com/login.
This is where your route is. Your redirect is redirecting **to** 'login'.

You named your route `vendor_login`. Therefore within the view, you have to write `<a href='{{{ route('vendor_login') }}}'>` to access your correct route.

Still, going to example.com/mysite/login will not show you your login page. It is available via example.com/login.
If you want to be available via example.com/mysite/login, use the following code.

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.com'), function()
{

  Route::get('/', function()
  {
      return Redirect::route('vendor_login');
  });

  Route::group(array('prefix' => 'mysite'), function()
  {
    Route::get('/login/', array('as' => 'vendor_login', 'uses' => 'AccountController@login'));
  });

});
```

The difference here is that the login route is now placed within a group that uses the 'mysite' prefix. In this case, your login route is available via example.com/mysite/login.
The redirect is changed from `Redirect::to('login')` (which redirected to example.com/login, to `Redirect::route('vendor_login')` which redirects to the named route vendor_login, independent of its path.

EDIT:
Routes are absolute. If you want to make a link that is relative to the same depth, in your view just do `<a href="login">Login</a>`. But this is not recommended. In that case you can not show the same view/link from routes with a different depth. Instead use named routes (as you did) which give you the most flexibility. Just put in your view the correct name `vendor_login` and change your Redirect::to to Redirect::route('vendor_login')

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, the vendor_login was a typo in the original. I was experimenting with changing names and left it in when I copied it here - I thought 'login' might have been a reserved word, so I tried changing the route name and the value of the link, but that didn't work. Also, the redirect::to already works - it's the route() call in the view that doesn't

Comment: Did you try putting it in only 2 brackets? {{route('login')}} . 3 brackets escape the characters, maybe that leads to a problem. 3 brackets should be used when you print content that is filled in by the user.

Comment: Tried that, doesn't help. It's not an escaping problem, it's with the domain